# Laravel does not show the highest value from the database

Tags: laravel

I has a code, which find max value in column:

```
$max_x = DB::table('bust_history')->max('bust_number');
```

But always the same value. Now the number 97.52 is displayed, from the field #30. But I have values also higher than this number, but the laravel does not want to display them. How can i fix this? For example, not highest value its 159.30, from fiend #550.

Comment: What is the column type? If it is varchar it sorts by place in ascii and not as a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your column in database probably is a `string` so because of that it consider it as `string` and not an `integer`or `float` and I think that's the cause of your problem. you have two ways in this case
First to change the `bust_number` to `int` or `float` (change your migration file etc)
<strike>Second is to cast it to `integer` in your model if you have a model for your `bust_history` table if so you just need to write</strike>

```
protected $casts = [
    'bust_number' => 'integer'
];
```

in your model...

Comment: You wouldn't want an `integer` if the values are like `97.52`. Also, I don't think casting will work; `max()` (and other functions) likely use the DB datatype to determine sorting; casting is done after the value is retrieved from the database.

Comment: @TimLewis Yea I kinda thought of it after I wrote the answer.

Comment: Haha yeah, your first suggestion is probably the better approach; modify the column type in the migration, but just not to an `integer`.

Comment: my column type is varchar. i try change `bust_number` to `int` it's work, but it show only integer number, but i need two digs after coma, can i make it without to change php files?

Comment: @ahab4ik probably `$table->decimal('bust_number',10, 2);` is the solution for you

Comment: @ahab4ik you can play with the numbers to get best result that works for you

Comment: @AH.Pooladvand  and I have 1 more question. data is entered into the table daily; can I also output the maximum number per day?

Comment: @ahab4ik if you are worry about slow query yea you can kinda do that you can `index` your column and you can `Cache` it if you don't want exact value each time you can see https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/cache for more information

Comment: @AH.Pooladvand can i use something like this `$max_x = DB::table('bust_history')->where('created_at', '>=', Carbon::today())->max('bust_number');` ?